.htaccess exposed to www since upgrade from apache 2.2 to 2.4
I just upgraded apache on my very old WHM server from 2.2 to 2.4, and now .htaccess files are being treated like text files instead of apache scripts.
I also installed mod_ruid2 0.98
These three lines are in the httpd.conf for each virtual host:
RDocumentChRoot /path/to/documentroot
RUidGid user group

then I also added the following:
<directory .>
AllowOverride All
</directory>

But that did not help.
The WHM/Cpanel scripts on my server won't help me unless I can install Apache with EasyApache but I can't even do that because the software is too "old" for them.
I did hack one script by commenting out lines of code and the best it can do is to copy the same old config even after I made changes. so the system must be mysteriously storing code somewhere.
Is there another way around this? or do I have to revert to installing apache 2.2 just to make configuration changes then install apache 2.4 again?

You mention cpanel so this question is most likely to be closed. See What topics can I ask about here?:

Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment.


and is not about:


working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel

According to the documentation The path in the directory directive must be a full path, not relative:

<Directory> Directive


Directory-path is either the full path to a directory, or a wild-card string using Unix shell-style matching. In a wild-card string, ? matches any single character, and * matches any sequences of characters.

